# How can I view how many unread emails I have in my Gmail inbox broken down by the sender's email address?

Tags: gmail

I use the Gmail website. I have 1000 unread emails. How can I view how many unread emails I have in my Gmail inbox broken down by the sender's email address?

I am aware that one can obtain a count of the unread email from one specific email address via the query `is:unread from:example@gmail.com`, but instead I would like to view the count for each sender at once, e.g.:

```
from:example1@gmail.com: 50 unread emails.
from:example2@gmail.com: 20 unread emails.
from:example3@gmail.com: 11 unread emails.
```

Comment: There is no built-in solution for this. If you are looking for software recommendation try [softwarerecs.se]. If you are open to use Google Apps Script show what you tried.

Comment: @Ruben Except for the search function that is meant for this exact purpose. That is what I did.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt I had more than 15k and cleared them out in about 45 minutes. Just search the most annoying/persistent ones first and delete page by page. You will be pleasantly surprised at the result. There is no point in finding an automated solution as I am guessing that you are not planning to repeat regularly. This may not be what you wanted to hear, but believe me, doing it page by page isn't as bad as it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of your comments:

> "the search function that is meant for this exact purpose. That is what I did."

Unfortunately the search function is for searching, it is not made to generate a report on the contents of your gmail account.

The options are to:

- use another tool to interact with your gmail; which can open its own can of worms
- write a Google apps script.